# Blender crashing when switching from Local View

Tags: object-mode

I am worked on an object in local view and closed the file. When I reopened and pressed / to exit out of local view, blender crashes with the following report: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S1KhYWFOeEeZn4SMASOorxrlNPPqXsNV/view?usp=sharing

Does anybody know what is happening and how I can prevent it?

Here is my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1thWMr4XQm9fXajqsQTja2_vH1J1SHHhF/view?usp=sharing